# ESS: retrieving command history from commands entered in ESS[R] inferior mode or script

Tags: r, emacs, ess

When using ESS[R] in inferior mode I can retrieve the most recent command output using C-c C-p which moves the cursor to the previous command output. Alternatively I can use C-up which essentially copies the most recently entered command from the inferior process (similar to how readline works). I  prefer the C-up approach but unfortunately it does not retrieve commands that were entered from a script using any of the ess-eval commads. Is there to get the functionality of C-up for commands entered in both inferior mode and by ess-eval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution works fine for single line commands, but needs a small tweak to handle multi-line statements:

```
(defun ess-readline ()
  "Move to previous command entered from script *or* R-process and copy 
   to prompt for execution or editing"
  (interactive)
  ;; See how many times function was called
  (if (eq last-command 'ess-readline)
      (setq ess-readline-count (1+ ess-readline-count))
    (setq ess-readline-count 1))
  ;; Move to prompt and delete current input
  (comint-goto-process-mark)
  (end-of-buffer nil) ;; tweak here
  (comint-kill-input)
  ;; Copy n'th command in history where n = ess-readline-count
  (comint-previous-prompt ess-readline-count)
  (comint-copy-old-input)
  ;; Below is needed to update counter for sequential calls
  (setq this-command 'ess-readline)
)
(global-set-key (kbd "\C-cp") 'ess-readline)
```

This enables you to move up through the previous commands; the following function enables you to move back down again, so you can go up and down to find the command you're after:

```
(defun ess-readnextline ()
  "Move to next command after the one currently copied to prompt and copy 
   to prompt for execution or editing"
  (interactive)
  ;; Move to prompt and delete current input
  (comint-goto-process-mark)
  (end-of-buffer nil)
  (comint-kill-input)
  ;; Copy (n - 1)'th command in history where n = ess-readline-count
  (setq ess-readline-count (max 0 (1- ess-readline-count)))
  (when (> ess-readline-count 0)
      (comint-previous-prompt ess-readline-count)
  (comint-copy-old-input))
  ;; Update counter for sequential calls
  (setq this-command 'ess-readline)
)
(global-set-key (kbd "\C-cn") 'ess-readnextline)
```

Comment: Thank you! It's also worth pointing out that neither solution may work on older versions of ESS and even in the newest version (14.9) this won't work on repeated calls to a multi-line command (this may be a bug in the current version of ESS). See https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/ess-help/2014-December/010373.html

Comment: Thank you! Excellent solution. 
This does not solve the problem of searching through previous executed commands. For example, comint-history-isearch-backward-regexp (M-r) searches only through comint history. Why doesn't ess place the evaluated command into the comint history?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem that there is any built in function to do this so I wrote the function below. Essentially this function automates the process of using the keystokes C-c C-p to move the cursor to a previous command in the R-process buffer followed by C-c RET to copy that command to the prompt for editing

```
(defun ess-readline ()
  "Move to previous command entered from script *or* R-process and copy 
   to prompt for execution or editing"
  (interactive)
  ;; See how many times function was called
  (if (eq last-command 'ess-readline)
      (setq ess-readline-count (1+ ess-readline-count))
    (setq ess-readline-count 1))
  ;; Move to end of buffer and delete current input
  (end-of-buffer nil)
  (comint-kill-input)
  ;; Copy n'th command in history where n = ess-readline-count
  (comint-previous-prompt ess-readline-count)
  (comint-copy-old-input)
  ;; Below is needed to update counter for sequential calls
  (setq this-command 'ess-readline)
)
(global-set-key (kbd "\C-cp") 'ess-readline)
```

Comment: You can bind this to C-up via `(define-key comint-mode-map [C-up] 'ess-readline)`